# grouping: for comprehensions in scala vs .net linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, scala

Reading about `for comprehensions` in scala I had a deja vu effect caused by .net's `linq`.
They both allow for a concise sequence definition.

Now - the question is how to concisely represent grouping using a `for comprehension`?

To be more specific. This in C#:

```
from entry in new[] {
    new { Name="Joe", ShoeSize="23" },
    new { Name="Alice", ShoeSize="23" },
    new { Name="Mary", ShoeSize="17" },
    new { Name="Yeti", ShoeSize="170" },
}
group entry by entry.ShoeSize into grouped
select grouped;
```

Produces:

```
Key=23, Items=(Joe, Alice)
Key=17, Items=(Mary)
Key=170, Items=(Yeti)
```

How to achieve the same concisely with scala `for comprehensions`?

Comment: Note that the question is about the features of scala `for comprehensions`, and not how to implement the above example in scala. However, I understood from the responses (the reason for +1s), that despite my today's 'deja vu' feeling, `for comprehensions` is a completely different thing than linq. It is used for creating sequences with filtering/selecting with the heavy lifting left out, whereas linq encompasses both. Or am I getting that wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala's for comprehension have no grouping ability. It is just a combination of `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` (actually, `withFilter`, but `filter` is easier to understand), or `foreach` and `filter`.

The principle behind them is *not* completely different, but LINQ was modeled after SQL, while for comprehension is modeled after monadic transformations. For instance, your example might be modeled with the following for comprehension:

```
for {
    (shoeSize, groups) <- entry groupBy (_.shoeSize)
    names = for (group <- groups) yield group.name
    grouped = (shoeSize, names)
} 
yield grouped
```

I expect LINQ is doing pretty much the same thing, but it includes these transformations as part of its basic syntax because it is expected.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of `for comprehensions`:

```
val entry = List(new { val name="Joe";   val shoeSize="23" },
                 new { val name="Alice"; val shoeSize="23" },
                 new { val name="Mary";  val shoeSize="17" },
                 new { val name="Yeti";  val shoeSize="170" })

val grouped = entry.groupBy(_.shoeSize)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `List#groupBy()` to group it by a certain field.

```
case class Person(name: String, shoeSize: Int)

val persons = List(
    Person("Joe", 23),
    Person("Alice", 23),
    Person("Mary", 17),
    Person("Yeti", 170)
)

val groupByShoeSize = persons.groupBy(_.shoeSize)

// Now groupByShoeSize is a Map[Int, List[Person]]

println(groupByShoeSize)

// Map((17,List(Person(Mary,17))), (23,List(Person(Joe,23), Person(Alice,23))), (170,List(Person(Yeti,170))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List("Joe"->"23",
     "Alice"->"23",
     "Mary"->"17",
     "Yeti"->"170").groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1))

//--> Map(23 -> List(Joe, Alice), 170 -> List(Yeti), 17 -> List(Mary))
```

Note that you can use case classes if you want named arguments (name and shoe size). The ugly `mapValues` part is only necessary to extract the name part from the tuple, elso you get `Map(23 -> List((Joe,23), (Alice,23)), 170 -> List((Yeti,170)), 17 -> List((Mary,17)))`, which is often "good enough".